Animating the vertex paint shade of a model to another vertex paint shade
I am trying to basically transition a base model male bust (from shoulders up) I scuplted in Blender into a Hulk like bust (much larger and gruesome looking). I was successful in doing so using Shape Keys. Now I am trying to figure out if there is a way gor me to key frame or somehow animate the color change from basic human skin tones to a greenish Hulk type color. I painted the base moxel using vertex paint and have searched the little key framing icons while in the Shader Editor and am unable to find any. Does anyone know of a way to transition between the two shaders so that the transition is animated along with the Shape key transition or animation?

You can Mix Shader and add keyframe to the factor with "i". Or Mix two colors and also "i" to keyframe factor. Did you try that or do you need help on that ?
